# find last child element of image

Tags: jquery, html

i have 16 images on image slider div. i have written code to dynamicaly add img in different classes. now i need to check if image is last one then add in last class.

i have written this code just to display alert if user clicks on last image .

```
 if($(this).is('img:last'))
        {
       alert('last child');
        }
        else
        {
            alert("atleast Nooooooooooooooo");
        }
```

This is not working . i have created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EdGBH/9/
[image]

last-child property is working in fiddle but in my slider its not working .Please help.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: a) set the jsfiddle so that it includes jQuery and then b) look in the error console and fix all syntax errors. At least in the fiddle it doesn't work mainly because of its invalid syntax.

Comment: Try `:last-child` http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/EdGBH/1/

Comment: I've updated the fiddle so that there are no parse errors and it uses jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

You have some problems in your code:

- Does not include jQuery library which you can choose from the sidebar in the `jsFiddle`
- You have redundant closing `})` at the end of your code.
- To determine whether your element is last child or not, you also can use:

  ```
  if($(this).is(':last-child'))
  ```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EdGBH/7/)**

Comment: In my Image slider 6 images are displayed ,if($(this).is(':last-child'))  is working in fiddle because i have removed sliding functionality.In my project it is not showing alert last child alert msg .. it is showing else condition on click of All images.

Comment: @simmisimmi Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: yours Fiddle is same as my code,only i have not added sliding function . center image is first image, here when i click on prev image  before first one (which is last image) i just want to print alert "Last child"

Answer (score 0):

After including jQuery in the JSFiddle and adding `$(document).ready(function(){` to the start of it, I can see no problems...

**[Here's what I've done.](http://jsfiddle.net/EdGBH/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

#### To answer your initial problem of adding the class to the last slide

Use the ":last-child" selector to get the last image (`img`) in the slider, then call `addClass` on it passing the class name "last" as the argument:

```
$("img:last-child").addClass("last");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EdGBH/8/

---

Not to say the other answers are poor, or wrong - they are completely correct, and you should definitely look into the suggestions regarding syntax and code quality.